# UnicodeEncodeError on Pycharm running HelloWorld

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed **Pycharm** on my computer. Trying to run just

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

I get the following output, with error

```
/usr/bin/python /home/roberto/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/202.6397.98/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=46501

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/home/roberto/Workspace/MyProject'])

PyDev console: starting.

Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
>>> runfile('/home/roberto/Workspace/MyProject/test.py', wdir='/home/roberto/Workspace/MyProject')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/roberto/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/202.6397.98/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's wrong with it?

Also, running `python --version` on my system shell I get

```
Python 2.7.18rc1
```

While if I try to install Python 3.8 through `sudo apt install python3.8` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I solve this issue? I guess I should somehow delete my Python 2.7 installation?

Comment: First of all why is it Python 2 intepreter

Comment: @Hedy maybe it's a problem with my python installation? Running `python --version` from my shell I still get `Python 2.7.18rc1`. You think updating to Python 3 would solve the issue?

Comment: If you already have Python 3 installed you can try changing your interpreter for Pytcharm, it might solve the problem. If it doesn't try `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` before executing

Comment: @Hedy I added something to the OP. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: I found the answer to my problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315015/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-after-installing-python-3-3/1147251#1147251 

Should I delete my question? I'm not sure

Comment: Could mark it as duplicate and put a link to that or something